# PHP While loop debugging

Tags: java, php, html

I am trying to create a simple while loop, but i am getting syntax errors. Could someone guide me on correcting them?

```
<? 
$count = 1;
While {$count<100)
{
    if ($count % 2){
    print "<p>8888</p>"
    }
    else{
    print "<p>7777</p>";
    count++
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your increment is stuck in an else statement.  Which means that if the first "if" is ever true, it will print 8888, not increment, be true again, print 8888 again, etc. in other words you're stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Come to think of it, what is the if statement supposed to be doing?  Because "if ($count % 2)" is always going to end up either "if(1)" or "if(0)".  I'm pretty sure it will always be considered true?  Well... I don't know how PHP interprets if statements on single integers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. While - while
2. Missing colons (`print "<p>8888</p>"`), (`count++`)
3. `{$count < 100)` - `($count < 100)`
4. `count` - `$count`

   ```
   <? 
   $count = 1;
   while ($count<100)
   {
       if ($count % 2){
       print "<p>8888</p>";
       }
       else{
       print "<p>7777</p>";
       }
       $count++;
   }
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It fails because you increment only if !($count % 2).
Try the following code:

```
<? 
$count = 1;
while ($count < 100)
{
    if ($count % 2){
        print "<p>8888</p>";
    } else {
        print "<p>7777</p>";
    }
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: are you shure with: count++?

Comment: $count++ for sure, my bad.

Comment: @NaN should take a look at this, too

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it makes much more sense now. But i am still getting 2 syntax errors at line 3 and after ?>

Comment: You accidentally wrote While {$count<100) instead of what it should be, While ($count<100)

Comment: @jeeps95 your ratio of errors to lines is quite high with this one :)

Comment: @NaN just goes to show how much i have to learn :D thanks again for all your help guys. Much appreciated

Comment: That's how it's going, learning by doing :)

Don't forget to mark the answers, so other people who might have similar problems can find the solution!

Comment: your answer still isnt quite right manniL as you still have a `{` where a `(` should be

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon

```
     print "<p>8888</p>";
```